# Install libraries for py27 with pre installed py3 Jupyter

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have been using Jupyter with py3 as a root. I installed it with Anaconda. Now I wanted to create a new kernel for py2. But after creating it, my old packages(like matplotlib) of py3 didn't get transferred to py2 and if I am trying to manually install them, it says they are already present. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you share the actual command line code you're using?

you should be able to do something like..

```
conda create -n Py27 python=2.7 anaconda matplotlib
```

and then have access to the libraries there.

You could then do

```
source activate Py27

jupyter notebook
```

and that should show you the py27 kernel

Comment: I tried some command line code from this http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3. The solution you have given works, but if I have to install a new module, which is there is py3 but not in Py27, how do I do that?

Comment: Create a new conda environment like I suggested and use python2 that way.

Do you mind sharing why you're trying to use python2?

and from the link you shared I still can't tell what you tried or what error you saw.

Comment: conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2  
python -m ipykernel install --user

I used these to create a new kernel but later, if I wanted to install a module, like matplotlib. If I try giving, "pip install matplotlib" it says it is already present as I installed it for py3. So I just want to know how do you install a module specifically for py2.

Comment: I have some code which is not working if I tried py3, I don't know why. But I actually, I want to shift to py2.

Comment: with your python2 environment activated pip installing matplot lib should work.

Comment: you don't need to do any of that "install --user" stuff. 

create the conda environment with a python2 kernel and then activate that environment and do your stuff. Everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! This conda thing is too confusing. I think it is better to install packages manually than using Anaconda.

Comment: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/blob/master/python/tutorials/mnist.ipynb

I tried to convert this. But I think I was wrong somewhere there, I thought going to py2 is easier.

Comment: yeah, i do the same thing. I notice a lot of tutorials I come across for DataScience stuff was done for Py2.7, so i keep a conda env with 2.7 on my system that i can switch to to watch the thing work, and then if i want to build something using what i learned, i build it up on Py3.

Comment: Anaconda can be really helpful managing all the supporting libraries needed for more complex math packages (pandas, sklearn, numpy, etc...)